# Error adding sublayer AVPlayer Shared Instance/Manager

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, avplayer

Im getting an error

> No visible @interfcae GlobalMediaPlayer declares selector add sublayer

.h

```
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    #import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

    @interface GlobalMediaPlayer : NSObject
    +(GlobalMediaPlayer *)sharedInstance;
    -(void)playFromURL:(NSString *)url;
```

.m

```
#import "GlobalMediaPlayer.h"


static GlobalMediaPlayer *sharedInstance = nil;

@interface GlobalMediaPlayer ()

{
    AVPlayer *avPlayer;
}

@end

@implementation GlobalMediaPlayer

-(id)init{
    if(self = [super init]){

    }
    return self;
}


+(GlobalMediaPlayer *)sharedInstance{

    if(!sharedInstance){
        sharedInstance = [[[self class] alloc] init];
    }
    return sharedInstance;
}

-(void)playFromURL:(NSString *)url{

    avPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.someurl/something.mp3"]];


    AVPlayerLayer *avPlayerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:avPlayer];
    avPlayerLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1920, 1020);
    //[self addSublayer:avPlayerLayer]; <---- No visible @interfcae GlobalMediaPlayer declares selector add sublayer error

    [avPlayer play];

}
```

using it

```
[[GlobalMediaPlayer sharedInstance] playFromURL:resourceUrl];
```

Comment: You're calling `addSublayer` on `self` which is a subclass of `NSObject` when you need to be calling it on a `CALayer` class, which is typically the `layer` property of one of your views.

Comment: Ok, any ideas how to call it on the class/view?

Comment: Assuming that a view controller is making the call to the singleton, you could pass that view controller's view as a second parameter - `[[GlobalMediaPlayer sharedInstance] playFromURL:resourceUrl inView:myView];`

Comment: `-(void)playFromURL:(NSString *)url inView:(UIViewController *)currentViewController;` gives me error expected type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no real advantage to wrapping `AVPlayer` code in a singleton, as the player needs to be able to render its video in a `CALayer` so it's typically best to have the player code in the `UIViewController` that is going to be presenting the content.

So in your view controller:

```
@interface MyViewController: UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) AVPlayer *player;
@property (nonatomic, weak) AVPlayerLayer *playerLayer;

@end

- (void)playFromURL:(NSString *)url {

    //Instantiate the player and player layer
    AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:url];
    AVPlayerLayer *playerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:player];

    //Add the player layer as a sublayer of the desired view or subview
    playerLayer.frame = self.view.frame;
    [self.view.layer addSublayer:playerLayer];

    [player play];

    //Retain a reference to the player and player layer for controls/removal
    self.avPlayer = player;
    self.playerLayer = playerLayer;

}
```

**Edit** I notice from your sample code that the URL points to an MP3. In that case you don't need to worry about creating an `AVPlayerLayer` at all. Simply instantiating the player and calling `play` is enough.

Comment: Yes I agree with there, im going to set it up in the individual views without wrapping it.  I already have the code in place for that I was just going to wrap it up for a couple of views I was calling it in.  I think as you said no advantage to that

Comment: Yeah what I normally do in that case is create a base video view controller and subclass that.

Comment: Just noticed your comment, brilliant, really no advantage now with only a line of code to play the url.  Thanks again,  plus 1 for the edit